# I have a one confusion on implementing an Objective-C singleton pattern?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
```

}

In above code off course we will get same address when each time we called method. But my question is that when this above method called for second time, why not it assign nil to sharedInstance object??? (static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;) How come it returns a previous address only?? it might be a silly question but i'm confused, please any one explain me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is declared as a static variable.  The static variable gets memory only once.  Thats why it returns same address whenever you call the above method

And dispatch_once will execute a block only once for the lifetime of an application.